# Windows 7 and vmware ubuntu images for multi-node Hadoop cluster - Configuration of IP addresses

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, cluster-computing

I am new to ubuntu and Hadoop...

My laptop has Windows 7 in it and it also has one Ubuntu VMWare Image (which i open using VMWare player).
My idea is to configure multi-node hadoop cluster on the same laptop.

Is it possible to have two ubuntu images each acting as a virtual machine, so that the cluster configuration can be simulated (although its not the ideal cluster)? If so, would these two virtual machines be able to communicate? Would i have to change the IP configuration etc to make this work?

```
VM 1 (ubuntu) - Hadoop master
VM 2 (ubuntu) - Hadoop slave
```

As an extension, is it possible for windows 7 also participate in the cluster?

```
Windows 7 - Hadoop master
VM 1 (ubuntu) - Hadoop slave 1
VM 2 (ubuntu) - Hadoop slave 2
```

Comment: Wow. this sounds intersting thing to do. i think Eric is right. please post the update.. i am eager to know how it goes :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, they should all be able to communicate with one another. VM to VM and VM to host.

To my knowledge, virtual machines connect to the network via virtual network adapters created by VMware player. This allows them to send and receive traffic just like any other machine connected to the local network. So you shouldn't have any problems connecting between all 3 of them.

So the Hadoop IP configuration would be the same, just treat them like machines on the local network.

Comment: Thanks @EricAlberson
As an extension to this question,
I have troubles in the ubuntu image. Its not stable after sometime. I noticed this pattern that when Firefox and Terminal are opened, then the VM hangs. I have allocated 512 MB of RAM to this VM. Do i need to do anything else to make it stable?
My laptop has 4 GB. Just wondering if its possible to configure one more VM. I am actually planning to configure the VMWare Hadoop image as VM2, so that i need not do the setup again. Only thing is it comes with a different flavour of Linux.

Comment: @ManikandanKannan 512MB isn't much to work with. I would start with trying to give them 1GB each (if you're only using 2). My laptop has 4GB of RAM and when I mess with a local cluster like you're describing, I use 2 VM's running with 1GB each. Give that a try, it should help. In that case you should only run programs like Firefox on your host. Don't run anything on the VMs that you don't have to. When I started on my VMs I used Hadoop without a desktop installed, so it was just command line, to save resources.

Comment: Thanks. It works just fine with 1 GB each. Let me monitor for some more time. On the original question, i am able to ssh from VM1 (ubuntu vmimage) to VM2 (hadoop vmimage). However when i read this tutorial [link](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-multi-node-cluster/), i see that its required to copy the generated public key on master to the slave. Is this required for hadoop to work or even SSH to work (i already have SSH working even without this copy)?

Comment: Yes, it is required. For Hadoop to run, the nodes obviously have to talk to each other. If you had to enter your password every time, it would simply be unusably slow. You need "passwordless" access from one VM to another. You may be able to SSH just fine already, but it's probably with a password. Copy the public key over like the tutorial explains to get passwordless access.

Comment: When i try to copy the data from local to dfs, i get this issue. I tried to reformat the node but still it does not work
**hdfs.DFSClient: DataStreamer Exception: java.io.IOException: Unable to create new block.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSClient.java:3002)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.access$2000(DFSClient.java:2255)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSClient.java:2446)**

Comment: i am able to make two VMs communicate, run the hadoop daemons from master which is able to communicate with slave. The only issue that i face now is when i copy the test data to dfs as mentioned in my previous comment. Once that is through, i think its just a matter of running the example map reduce program. Do you have any clue on this data copy issue?

Comment: That's not a problem I've ever encountered, sorry.